# Habilitar y deshabilitar campos en un formulario html

Tags: php, html

Mi duda es la siguiente:

¿Es posible habilitar o deshabilitar un campo de un formulario desde PHP?.

Dependiendo de un número que extraigo de una base de datos:

- si el número que extraigo es `4894-rt`, que se me habilite un campo en el formulario donde ingresare un dato pata que haga un calculo.
- pero si extraigo `465456-t`, no ocupo que se me habilite el campo, sino que se mantenga oculto.

Comment: Puedes ser mas especifico? El usuario puede desactivar o activar el campo dependiendo de opciones que el seleccione? O antes de mostrar el formulario tu quieres que campos esten deshabilitados?

Comment: si es antes de mostrar el formulario lo puedes hacer con php pero si es después sino me equivovo lo deberás hacer con javascript o jquery

Comment: Depende de un numero que extraigo de una base de datos. ej:  si el numero que extraigo es 4894-rt lo que ocupario es que se me habilite un campo en el formulario donde ingresare un dato pata que haga un calculo. pero si extraigo 465456-t no ocupo que se me habilite el campo sini que se mantengo oculto

Comment: Hola @use2105. ¡Bienvenido a [es.so]! Agregué tu comentario dentro de la pregunta. Para aclarar cuestiones de lo que estás preguntando, encontrarás el enlace a [edit] debajo de tu pregunta.

Comment: O simplemente colocas el atributo disabled="disabled" en el input al que quieres bloquear y ya

Comment: No es claro si lo quieres hacer al cargar el formulario o como resultado de alguna petición ajax (con el formualrio ya cargado). Tampoco está incluido el código y lo que se está intentando para obtener el resultado deseado.

Answer (score 4):

Ok te paso un ejemplo sencillo:

```
$numero = 1;
$disabled = '';
if($numero == 1){
    $disabled = 'disabled';
}
echo "<input type='text' $disabled>";
```

Answer (score 1):

Aunque la respuesta es "Si" (por ejemplo recargando la pagina con parámetros get en la URL), creo que es mucho mejor utilizar JavaScript o jQuery.

En JavaScript por ejemplo para deshabilitar:

```
document.getElementById("idInputEnElDom").disabled = true; // deshabilitar
document.getElementById("idInputEnElDom").disabled = false; // habilitar
```

En Jquery

```
$("#idInputEnElDom").prop('disabled', true); // deshabilitar
$("#idInputEnElDom").prop('disabled', false); // deshabilitar

$(".claseInputEnElDom").prop('disabled', true); // deshabilitar por clase, posibilita deshabilitar multiples campos con una instrucción
```

Ojo, en el lado del servidor tendras que controlar el caso, ya que las limitaciones del lado del cliente se pueden saltar.

Saludos

Comment: El autor puso en comentarios las condiciones para que se muestre el campo y lo incorporé a la pregunta.

Answer (score 0):

Puedes probar algo así, que compruebe el valor de $bdresult que es lo que obtienes en la BD y según el valor muestras el campo habilitado o deshabilitado.

Ejemplo:

```
<?php
if ($bdresult === "4894-rt") {
    echo '<input type="text" value="abc">';
} elseif ($bdresult === "465456-t") {
    echo '<input type="text" value="abc" disabled>';
} else {
    echo 'otra cosa';
}
?>
```

Comment: @Mikel  gracias  por la corrección, al hacer tan rápido el ejemplo no me había dado cuenta

Answer (score 0):

> se puede deshabilidar un campo de un formulario y con lenguaje php habilitarlo cuando lo necesite.??

Si, tan solo debes agregar al campo del formulario el atributo **disabled**.
Por ejemplo:

```php
<form>
  <label> Nombre: </label>
  <input type="text"<?php if ($desactivar) { ?> disabled<?php } ?> />
</form>
```